# how to define new type including itself?

Tags: scala, recursion, types, recursive-type

In scala I am wondering if there is a way I can define a new type including itself
For example

```
type A = Tuple(e1: Int, e2: A)
```

Ofcourse type `A = List[A]` is illegal so is there another way to do this?

I tried doing this with type `Any` and `Option` but it didn't go well, and I am not sure this is a right way to do this

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
sealed trait A
case class Tuple(e1: Int, e2: A) extends A
```

Now there is no way to construct a value of type `A` (not using `null`) so you should add a "leaf" besides the "fork" `Tuple`.

Infinite recursive type `type A = Tuple[Int, A]` is forbidden

```scala
case class Tuple[A, B](e1: A, e2: B)

type A = Tuple[Int, A] // doesn't compile
//A is already defined as type A
```

For recursive calculations on types you can use [type projections](https://apocalisp.wordpress.com/2010/06/08/type-level-programming-in-scala/)

```
trait AddOneLevel[A] {
  type Out = Tuple[Int, A]
}

type X[A] = AddOneLevel[AddOneLevel[AddOneLevel[A]#Out]#Out]#Out

type A
implicitly[X[A] =:= Tuple[Int, Tuple[Int, Tuple[Int, A]]]] // compiles
```

and

```
sealed trait Nat {
  type This <: Nat
  type ++ = Succ[This]
  type AddNLevels[A]
}
class Succ[N <: Nat] extends Nat {
  type This = Succ[N]
  type AddNLevels[A] = Tuple[Int, N# AddNLevels [A]]
}
object Zero extends Nat {
  type This = Zero
  type AddNLevels[A] = A
}
type Zero  = Zero.type
type One   = Succ[Zero]
type Two   = Succ[One]
type Three = Succ[Two]

implicitly[Three# AddNLevels [String] =:= Tuple[Int, Tuple[Int, Tuple[Int, String]]]] // compiles
```

Another option is [type classes](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/main/core/shared/src/main/scala/shapeless/ops/nat.scala)

```
import shapeless.Lazy

trait AddOneLevel[A] {
  type Out
}
object AddOneLevel {
  type Aux[A, Out0] = AddOneLevel[A] {type Out = Out0}

  implicit def recurse[A, B](implicit
    aol: /*=>*/ Lazy[AddOneLevel.Aux[A, B]]
  ): Aux[A, Tuple[Int, B /*aol.value.Out*/]] = null

  implicit def base[A]: Aux[A, Tuple[Int, A]] = null
}

implicitly[AddOneLevel.Aux[String, Tuple[Int, String]]] // compiles
implicitly[AddOneLevel.Aux[String, Tuple[Int, Tuple[Int, String]]]] // compiles
implicitly[AddOneLevel.Aux[String, Tuple[Int, Tuple[Int, Tuple[Int, String]]]]] // compiles
```

(For some reason [Scala 2.13](https://github.com/scala/scala/releases/v2.13.0) [by-name implicits](https://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/byname-implicits.html) `=>` and path-dependent type `aol.value.Out` do not work in 2.13.10: [1](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/fshXTCahSAWt26FBzzwZVQ/1) [2](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/fshXTCahSAWt26FBzzwZVQ/3)).

In Scala 3 you can use [match types](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/new-types/match-types.html) and [compile-time operations](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/metaprogramming/compiletime-ops.html#the-scalacompiletimeops-package)

```
import scala.compiletime.ops.int.-

type AddNLevels[A, N <: Int] = N match {
  case 0 => A
  case _ => Tuple[Int, AddNLevels[A, N - 1]]
}

summon[AddNLevels[String, 3] =:= Tuple[Int, Tuple[Int, Tuple[Int, String]]]] // compiles
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be a confusion between types and classes. The original example is not a valid type declaration, and looks much more like a class declaration.

The closest (invalid) type declaration would be

```
type A = Tuple2[Int, A]
```

The class declaration would look like this:

```
class A(e1: Int, e2: A)
```

This is valid but not particularly useful as you need an instance of `A` to create an `A` and have to resort to `null` to get started.